# Dynamic Content with DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

I have a MasterDE which contains the OptIn Status as field. The DE is linked in Data Designer with Contact record via 1-1 relation (SubscriberKey is promary).

I now do want to build an email with dynamic Content based on the criteria if the OptIn field (boolean) is true or false. If I test the email based on my recordId from All subsriber List, it doesn't work, if I change to MasterDE it works.

Doesn't the dynamic content tool support data relations?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that Contact Builder sets "cardinality"(how different attributes map to a single contact) while the personalization is powered by data relationship and look ups.

You need to test it on a Data extension that has the required field for you Ampscript field. Email Studio is responsible your email sends/ personlization, while contact builder handles your data model for other modules (especially Journey builder).

You need to ensure that your primarykey relations and look ups are pointing the right data extensions.

You cant use "primarykeys" on lists.

Comment: I don't want to use Dynamic Content with AMPscript, I do want to use the dynamic content tool in the email studio.

Comment: can you post an example what you have placed in your dynamic content wizard?

Comment: You can only create Dynamic Content based on Profile Attributes or the Sendable Data Extension you're sending to/previewing with. If you need to personalise based on a related table, use AMPScript or Guild Template Language.